# Uninstall MySQL from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, mysql

I am trying to uninstall MySQL completely from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,but I am facing an issue saying:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   mariadb-client-10.0 : Depends: libdbd-mysql-perl (>= 1.2202) but it is not going to be installed
>   mariadb-client-core-10.0 : Depends: mariadb-common (>= 10.0.24-7) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

I tried also to uninstall Mariadb but I have always the same problem. 
Any idea !!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I finally uninstall MySQL completely, and reinstall it using these lines :

Remove all files related to MySQL

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then upgrade my distribution

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then install MySQL

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

That's all.

Comment: I had to remove `dbconfig-mysql` first. But, thanks!

Comment: @Tico - That was what  made whole difference. I tried every way to 'purge' and install old mysql-server but it  didn't work. Once i did `sudo apt-get purge dbconfig-mysql` and did other removals and install, it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArvindK. I'm glad it also helped out

Answer (score 17):

As [Tico](https://askubuntu.com/users/199716/tico) pointed out, if you installed `dbconfig-mysql` uninstall that first

This worked for me

```
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
```

after that I could continue with removing `mysql-client` and `mysql-server`