# Mysql on Ubuntu 16.04: cannot log in as root, cannot start in safe mode, /var/run/mysqld removed at reboot

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I can't get mysql working with Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS-13 9360, mysql version 5.7.17. There seem to be two problems:

1) I can’t log in as root, or superuser, or start mysql in safe mode.

2) The folder `/var/run/mysqld` is removed when the service is stopped.

Here are the details;

I’ve purged and reinstalled mysql by running these commands ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776845/uninstall-mysql-from-ubuntu-16-04)) in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Reinstalled it with:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

After installation, when I type either of these commands in the terminal:

```
mysql -uroot
```

or

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

I see this message:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

I tried to start mysql in safe mode by these commands:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

which fails with this message:

```
2017-04-26T08:54:42.307043Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2017-04-26T08:54:42.309096Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-04-26T08:54:42.311019Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-04-26T08:54:42.313024Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

I can get mysql working temporarily by entering these commands which I found at [After fresh install of mysql-server, can't log in with `mysql root -u`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327120/after-fresh-install-of-mysql-server-cant-log-in-with-mysql-root-u):

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

This replaces the missing file and starts mysql in safe mode. Then in a new terminal:

```
mysql -uroot
SET PASSWORD for root@localhost = password('test')
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
\q
```

stop and restart mysql in normal mode

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

After this I can log in using either:

```
sudo mysql -uroot
```

or

```
mysql -u root -p
```

BUT if I stop and restart the service again, then I can’t log in. If I enter:

```
sudo mysql -uroot
```

I see this error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Also when I reboot the computer, the whole problem recurs.
I tried the workaround in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1435823); I created a file `mysql.conf` containing this code:

```
# systemd tmpfile settings for mysql
# See tmpfiles.d(5) for details

d /var/run/mysqld 0755 mysql mysql -
```

and I saved it in these locations:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
/etc/tmpfiles.d
```

But it has made no difference.

I'd be very grateful for any information that can help me get mysql working!

Comment: Did you set a password for root when installing using the secure installation step?

Comment: As you change the password of root try to login like this: `mysql -u root -p test`

Comment: I was not asked for a password when installing. I've only done the commands listed above, not the secure installation step.

I don't think it can be that I have the wrong password, because the problem recurs AFTER I set the password, login successfully, then reboot.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, if I enter "mysql -u root -p test" I am still asked to enter my password and then I see an error message "ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test'".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the original problem was caused by not setting a password for root when I first installed mysql. This used to be normal for local development but it seems that in mysql 5.7.17, this causes all sorts of problems, and setting a password later doesn't fix it.

This was compounded by me not uninstalling mysql properly when trying again.

In the end, what worked was to uninstall mysql using:

```
sudo apt purge mysql*
```

Remove /etc/mysql folder

Remove /var/lib/mysql, /var/lib/mysql-files, /var/lib/mysql-keyring folders.

Reboot

Install mysql using:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Make sure to set a password for root!

Comment: Just be sure to also back up your /var/lib/mysql if you care about the databases' data.